# Event manager applet not getting recognized for Cisco ASA ver8.0

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, cisco-eem

I need help as Event manager applet not getting recognized for Cisco ASA ver8.0. But for cisco ASA ver 9.6 it is working properly. Please advise

```
BnglASA/pri/act(config)#Event manager applet backupconfig
BnglASA/pri/act(config-applet) # description "Monthly backup of ASA" 
BnglASA/pri/act(config-applet) # event timer watchdog time 108000
BnglASA/pri/act (config-applet #action 1 cli command "copy /noconfirm running-config ftp://utiftp:v7V5fasffas@10.X.X.X/"
BnglASA/pri/act(config-applet) #output none
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The feature was introduced in version 9.2.1:

[*Release Notes for the Cisco ASA Series, 9.2(x)*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa92/release/notes/asarn92.html#pgfId-773511)

> We introduced or modified the following commands: **event manager
>   applet, description, event syslog id, event none, event timer, event
>   crashinfo, action cli command, output, show running-config event
>   manager, event manager run, show event manager, show counters protocol
>   eem, clear configure event manager, debug event manager, debug menu
>   eem**.

-and-

[*ASA Embedded Event Manager Configuration Example*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/adaptive-security-appliance-asa-software/117883-config-eem-00.html)

> This document describes Embedded Event Manager (EEM), which is a
>   troubleshooting tool that was added in Adaptive Security Appliance
>   (ASA) Version 9.2(1). The functionality is similar to Cisco IOS? based
>   EEM. It is a powerful way to run CLI commands based on ASA events
>   (syslogs) and save the output. This document covers an introduction to
>   the feature as well as some example EEM applets.